# How to do the total sum of a group by?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table

```
Name    Val
Test1   $100.00 
Test2   $200.00 
Test3   $300.00 
Test4   $400.00 
Test5   $500.00
```

I am able to retrieve val by group with :

```
SELECT Name,sum(Val) FROM Synthese WHERE Name IN ( 'Test1' , 'Test2' , 'Test3') GROUP BY Name
```

Which give me the following output :

```
Name    Val
Test1   $100.00 
Test2   $200.00 
Test3   $300.00
```

But I don't know how to do :

```
sum(val)/(val(Test1)+val(Test2)+val(Test3))
```

Numerical example :

```
100/(100+200+300)
200/(100+200+300)
300/(100+200+300)
```

How should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, 
     sum(Val)/(SELECT sum(Val) FROM Synthese WHERE Name IN('Test1','Test2','Test3'))
FROM Synthese 
WHERE Name IN('Test1','Test2','Test3') 
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: Damn didn't knew it was possible to do SELECT of SELECT ! Thank you

Comment: You missed WHERE : `SELECT Name, sum(Val) / (select sum(Val) FROM Synthese WHERE Name IN ( 'Test1' , 'Test2' , 'Test3') )
FROM Synthese 
WHERE Name IN ( 'Test1' , 'Test2' , 'Test3') 
GROUP BY Name`

Maybe correct this mistake on the post